# How apply active curent state to a CSS sprite?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem to add current (active) dynamic state a sprites for page (active state should be in circle). Check this please.

```css
.language{
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 92px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.lang-c{
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  text-indent: -10000px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.lang-en {
  background: url("http://aero.artnova.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/lang-en.png") no-repeat top left;
}
.lang-en:hover {
  background: url("http://aero.artnova.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/lang-en.png") no-repeat 0 -34px;
}
.lang-pl {
  background: url("http://aero.artnova.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/lang-pl.png") no-repeat top left;
}
.lang-pl:hover {
  background: url("http://aero.artnova.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/lang-pl.png") no-repeat 0 -34px;
}
.lang-ru {
  background: url("http://aero.artnova.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/lang-ru.png") no-repeat top left;
}
.lang-ru:hover{
  background: url("http://aero.artnova.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/lang-ru.png") no-repeat 0 -34px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="language">
  <a href="http://aero.artnova.com.pl/?lang=ru"><li class="lang-c lang-ru"></li></a>
  <a href="http://aero.artnova.com.pl/?lang=pl"><li class="lang-c lang-pl"></li></a>
  <a href="http://aero.artnova.com.pl/"><li class="lang-c lang-en"></li></a>
</ul>
```

You can also check it on page http://aero.artnova.com.pl/
Thank for help.

Comment: You should trigger a class through JavaScript on the active one if this localization is being done on client, or on your server rendering otherwise. Then through CSS, you can style that class.

Comment: What's more `a` must be inside `li`.

Comment: You can't do this with JS because the site is refreshing after click. You should add active class inside Your change language template in PHP.

Comment: @3rdthemagical there's no reason the <li> can't be inside  <a>.

Comment: Maybe any Magic PHP Man know how to resolve and could be write quick solution :)

Comment: TIP: I use WPML plugin https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/language-setup/custom-language-switcher/

Answer (score 1):

you can active using css,just use like this

```
html:lang(pl-PL) .lang-pl{
  background: url("http://aero.artnova.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/lang-pl.png") no-repeat 0 -34px;
}
```

you have to find the lang attribute and write for rest of the elements